# How to make a formula result in a cell containing strings appear as a percentage?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the cell entry:

```
="Males: "&COUNTIF(D2:D55,"Male")& " / "& ROUND(COUNTIF(D2:D55,"Male")/COUNTA(D2:D55),2)
```

in a cell, which returns the output:

```
Males: 22 / 0.41
```

This is almost perfect, except I would like the output to read:

```
Males: 22 / 41%
```

However, clicking the percentage format button doesn't work, I suspect because it's a cell containing multiple data types and text strings. Every guide I've been able to Google assumes that you can press the percentage format button to change the data display type.

What can I do?

Comment: `TEXT` function.

Comment: Won't that give me "0.41%" instead of "41%"? Sorry if I'm having a brain fart.

Comment: `0.41` formatted is `41%`.